# How to get x:Name of control to use it in ViewModel in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making a custom control of an Entry and I need to get the x: Name of the Entry to use it in the ViewModel of my project to get the cursor position when I use it.

This is my code:

This is my xaml of custom control:

```html
  <Entry
                        x:Name="EntryControl"
                        Margin="45,0,0,0"
                        Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=Placeholder}"
                        Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                        WidthRequest="320" />
```

I want to get this x:Name to use in in ViewModel.

Comment: it's bad MVVM design to have your VM and your View tightly coupled together like this.  However, if you must do it, you can just pass a reference to the Entry when you create your VM

Comment: Is there another way to do what I want? Can I get my Entry position without doing a bad practice?

Comment: you haven't explained what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: I have an Entry control in a custom control. The entry control has a property that is "Entry.CursorPosition". Get the position where the cursor is to be able to write text where my cursor is. I want to be able to use this property from the viewmodel.

Comment: then just bind that property to the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jason said , you could binding the value of **CursorPosition** .

The property is bindable so we could set it like

```
<Entry
            CursorPosition="{Binding Position,Mode=TwoWay}"
            x:Name="EntryControl"
            Margin="45,0,0,0"
            Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=Placeholder}"
            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
            WidthRequest="320" />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Color> MySource { get; set; }


        int position;

        public int Position
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }

            set
            {
               // it will been called when we edit the entry
                if(position != value)
                {
                    position = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Position");
                    // do some thing you want 
                    
                }
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
          

        }
       

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a problem now, I needed this to be able to put emojis when pressing a button where the cursor was. The problem is that when I press an emoji button, the keyboard closes (so when the keyboard is closed the cursor is removed). How can I make the keyboard stay open when I tap on another side of the screen?

Comment: I undeleted the post

Comment: I created a new post.